# Specific data from worksheet not copying over to another correctly - Runtime error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "Data" worksheet that holds data. It has 20 columns A-U and in the G column is the date that is meant for dd/mm/yyyy. I have a separate worksheet called "NoEntry" and here is where I would like the dates to be entered by the user (Start-date L15 and End-date in L16) and once a button clicked all the data between and including the start and end date will go into another worksheet called "DateData".

The code I have below does not work at all and I don't know why. The error message I get is: Run-time error 1004:

[image: Debug Error]

[image: Line of code Error]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsDate As Worksheet, wsNoEntry As Worksheet
Dim dSDate As Date, dEDate As Date
Dim lRowStart As Long, lRowEnd As Long
Dim aData() As Variant
Dim i As Long


'set the worksheet objects
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set wsDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DateData")
Set wsNoEntry = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NoEntry")

'required variables
dSDate = wsNoEntry.Range("L15").Value
dEDate = wsNoEntry.Range("L16").Value

'set the array - you can make this dynamic!
aData = wsData.Range("A1:U1000").Value

'for loop to find start
For i = 1 To 1000
    If aData(i, 7) = dSDate Then
        lRowStart = i
        Debug.Print "Start row = " & lRowStart
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

'now loop backwards to find end date
For i = 1000 To 1 Step -1
    If aData(i, 7) = dEDate Then
        lRowEnd = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

'now we have start and end dates
'going to use copy/ paste for simplicity
wsData.Range("A" & lRowStart, "U" & lRowEnd).Copy
'paste in date sheet
wsDate.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
'clear clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image: NoEntry Worksheet]

[image: Data worksheet]

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you checked the values of `lRowStart` and `lRowEnd` when you get to `wsData.Range("A" & lRowStart, "U" & lRowEnd).Copy`? I suspect your issue is that your variables don't have a value set

Comment: Check that `lRowStart` and `lRowEnd` have values. And if you are looking to copy that range should be: `wsData.Range("A" & lRowStart & ":U" & lRowEnd).Copy`

Comment: @Zac So on the data worksheet I don't have data anywhere from what I showed on the screenshot. How would I make it dynamic

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego So on the data worksheet I don't have data anywhere else from what I showed on the screenshot. How would I make it dynamic so it just goes to the last row. Sorry I don't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsDate As Worksheet, wsNoEntry As Worksheet
Dim dSDate As Date, dEDate As Date
Dim lRowStart As Long, lRowEnd As Long
Dim aData() As Variant
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    

Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Set wsDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DateData")
Set wsNoEntry = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NoEntry")


dSDate = wsNoEntry.Range("L15").Value
dEDate = wsNoEntry.Range("L16").Value
j = 1

For i = 1 To 1000
    If wsData.Cells(i, 7).Value >= dSDate and wsData.Cells(i, 7).Value <= dEDate Then
        Range("A" & i & ":U" & i).Copy Destination:=wsDate.Range("A" & j)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method on line If wsData(i, 7) >= dSDate and wsData(i, 7) <= dEDate Then

Comment: Thanks for the code above unsure why this error message is happening

Comment: Sorry... It was my mistake... Edited

Comment: No worries, I am getting no error message now but when I click the button nothing happens. So data doesn't transfer over.

Comment: @Donald place msgbox and check the values of L15, L16 and `wsData.Cells(i, 7).Value >= dSDate and wsData.Cells(i, 7).Value <= dEDate` values

Comment: sorry to be a pain but I am not too sure how to do that. Debug.print(dsDate) maybe?

Comment: I already add 2 msgbox on the code. That is a quick way to see if you are getting values or one loop or condition as expected

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't notice. I have ran the code and both start and end date were correctly printed in a message box

Comment: So the data is ok. Delete those msgbox and place 1 in the condition as trigger

Comment: Where about in the condition and what shall I print?

Comment: I already edit again. I hope you will understand how it works. That will show you a Message confirming if rhe conditions are true... If they are, the code will copy. In fact, it should work

Comment: So I run the code and it displayed a message box - both are true, I click okay for 9 times then it becomes true, false 10 times becomes false, true then I cant get out of the box - can click okay indefinitely.

Comment: The code did not copy also - I couldn't get out of the message box - seems like its looping forever

Comment: So it is correct as in the conditions are being met. The 9th record I changed the date to be above the end date and it read false so it worked and rest were True and True. However I was then left in a loop and no data transferred over

Comment: When you want to break the code just press Ctrl+Break. If the conditions are ok, the loop is working as well as the conditions. It seems a continuous because your original post were for 1000 items. Reduce the loop

Comment: Anyhow, instead of Range("A" ... Try by Cells(i.7) to check the copy instruction

Comment: Hi David, could you remove the comments for the loop as I have forgot how it was meant to be? I have tried but keep getting error messages. Sorryy for the inconvenience.

Comment: As in the debug comments to see if goes through the rows

Comment: Comments removed

Comment: Sorry David I didn't mean the comments I meant the debug message you wrote so that it prints true, true or true false. I just want it to run. Sorry it was my fault for not being clear